# Python - Чтение файла построчно, и запись строк в переменную

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть файл file.txt
И в нем есть текст `123
321`

Мне надо сделать так, что бы 123 присвоилось к переменной "a", а 321 к переменной "b"

Кто знает как это осуществить?

Comment: `a = fp.readline()` и `b = fp.readline()` где `fp` это ваш открытый файл

Comment: @andreymal Уже разобрался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я еще не работал с текстовыми файлами, по этому попробовал на строке, понимаю что не то, но думаю смысл решения ты уловишь

```
text = '123 321 228 1488'
dict = dict()
for i in range(len(text.split(' '))):
    for j in text.split(' '):
        dict[i] = j`
```

в сплит тебе нужно будет указать '\n', наверно